# Función recursiva en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursión

Tengo esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
    winner            CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL ,
    successor              CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL ,
    data           NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_win_succ PRIMARY KEY (winner, successor)
);
```

Con estos datos:

```
INSERT INTO players VALUES
  ('Helen','Sharon',12),
  ('Helen','Martina',34),
  ('Martina','Sharon',2),
  ('Claudia','Steffi',35),
  ('Sharon','Penny',5),
  ('Meg','Claudia',21),
  ('Penny','Meg',3),
  ('Steffi','Helen',230);
```

Lo que necesito es una función que recorra las ganadoras al dar una jugadora inicial y otra final cualquiera.

Por ejemplo, si cojo a `Sharon` como inicial y `Meg` como final, tendría que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Initial | Final | List of winners | Total Data | Number of Winners |
Sharon | Meg | Sharon - Penny - Meg | 8 | 3
```

Si es cogiera a `Claudia` como inicial y a `Sharon` como final este sería el resultado:

```
Initial | Final | List of winners | Total Data | Number of Winners |
Claudia | Sharon | Claudia - Steffi - Helen - Sharon | 277 | 4
Claudia | Sharon | Claudia - Steffi - Helen - Martina - Sharon | 301 | 5
```

Lo he modificado para que muestre las diferentes alternativas en las que se puede encontrar y mostrar cada alternativa en una fila. Es en este punto en el que me he atascado, gracias!!! ^^

Comment: Lo he modificado un poco. 
La lógica es que siempre se inicia y se acaba en winner pero pasando por las diferentes winner y sucesoras. Otro ejemplo sería, quiero ir de Penny a Steffi y sería: Penny - Meg - Claudia - Steffi
Espero haberme explicado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un ejercicio interesante. Esta es la consulta que funcionó para mi. Simplemente ajusta los 2 lugares donde te dejé el comentario para cambiar la persona de inicio y final:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select 1 as level,
         winner,
         successor,
         data
    from players
   where winner = 'Claudia' -- modifica aquí para cambiar el inicio
   union all
  select c.level + 1 as level,
         p.winner,
         p.successor,
         p.data
    from cte c
    join players p
      on p.winner = c.successor
   where c.winner <> 'Sharon' -- modifica aquí para cambiar el final
)
select max(case when level = 1 then winner end) as "Initial",
       max(case when reverse_level = 1 then winner end) as "Final",
       string_agg(winner, ' - ' order by level) as "List of winners",
       sum(case when reverse_level <> 1 then data end) as "Total Data",
       count(*) as "Number of Winners"
  from (select *,
               row_number() over (order by level desc) as reverse_level
          from cte) t;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/BGJ71189)</kbd>

Para lograrlo, usé las técnicas siguientes:

- Una expresión de tabla común recursiva ([`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)) para navegar los registros de forma recursiva.
- La función ventana [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) para poder identificar el último registro.
- Funciones de agregación condicionales (`MAX(CASE ... END)`).
- La función [`STRING_AGG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) para combinar la lista de ganadores en un solo campo.

## Edición

Con los ajustes a la pregunta, tuve que modificar la técnica general. Sigo usando el `WITH RECURSIVE` para navegar los registros de forma recursiva. Pero a diferencia de mi consulta anterior, en vez de usar funciones de agregación al final para obtener los resultados deseados, mas bien voy a efectuando la agregación de forma progresiva directamente en el `WITH RECURSIVE`. Luego filtro los registros para que solo me queden los que terminan con la persona "final".

Notarás que con esta consulta, debes especificar la persona de inicio en 1 lugar, y la persona final en 2 lugares:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select winner,
         successor,
         winner as inicial,
         successor as final,
         winner || ' - ' || successor as list_winners,
         data::numeric(10,2) as total_data,
         2 as num_winners
    from players
   where winner = 'Claudia' -- modifica aquí para cambiar el inicio
   union all
  select p.winner,
         p.successor,
         c.inicial,
         p.successor as final,
         c.list_winners || ' - ' || p.successor as list_winners,
         (c.total_data + p.data)::numeric(10,2) as total_data,
         c.num_winners + 1 as num_winners
    from cte c
    join players p
      on p.winner = c.successor
     and p.winner <> 'Sharon'-- modifica aquí para cambiar el final
)
select inicial as "Initial",
       final as "Final",
       list_winners as "List of winners",
       total_data as "Total Data",
       num_winners as "Number of Winners"
  from cte
 where final = 'Sharon'; -- modifica aquí para cambiar el final
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/WCP74310)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación,aprendo más aquí que con muchos libros.
He realizado una variación sobre el ejercicio, he puesto que pueda haber varias vías hasta llegar al destino y que muestre esas alternativas en filas.Llevo horas atascada ahí. Gracias! ^^

Comment: O sea que cambiastes la pregunta :(  Típicamente, eso no se hace. Mas bien, se abre una nueva pregunta para evitar invalidar respuestas existentes. Pero bueno, para la próxima vez.

Comment: Ok, agregué una edición a la respuesta para manejar mas de una alternativa.

Comment: Para la próxima sin duda. Gracias ^^

Comment: Excelente explicación maestro @sstan